# Android Studio AVD http request to Visual Studio 2015 IIS C# Service

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2015, android-virtual-device

I've got app running on an AVD that generates a http GET request. This points to an endpoint running in VS2015. VS2015 provides me with http://localhost:7071 as the target to use, but you can't use localhost on an AVD as the AVD thinks you're targeting it and you'll receive access denied. I have tried targeting 10.0.2.2:7071 and 127.0.0.1:7071 as suggested elsewhere, but nothing works. Either it's access denied or host cannot be found.

localhost:7071 definitely is live though as I can get an access denied page in Chrome, so that's a valid response.

How do you set this up so that it will work?

Comment: In your PC, use web browser to check if you can access "http://192.1...:7071" or not (let's assume your PC has IP 192.1... If cannot, add that IP into applicationHost file inside IISExpress (inside Documents folder).

Answer (score 0):

As I have commented, let's assume your PC's IP address is `192.168.1.100`, you should try access `http://192.168.1.100:7071` from Chrome inside your PC to make sure it's accessbile. If error 404 (not found), go to `%UserProfile%\Documents\IISExpress\config`, update your app config like the following sample (pay attention to the line with **IP address**)

```
           <site name="MyAppDemo" id="123">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="..." />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:7071:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:7071:192.168.1.100" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

Then, re-check both from your PC and your Android client.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by installing IIS in Windows components. Then instead of running IIS Express, I changed the web server in VS2015 project properties to Local IIS. This let me access localhost/websitename on my AVD device.